# How to deploy Path : Duplicate RecordType error

Tags: deployment, metadata, change-set

I am trying to deploy the path one org to another org, I am getting the error that duplicate record type.

In the source org, the path has default "--Master--" record type.

What else we need to include in the package?

I have added, 1. PathAssistant, 2. Picklist

**Source org:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, there was already a duplicate path existing for that object. That is why it is not allowing me deploy another one.

Regards,
Ajay